# Get the total amount of visitors under this week and last week

Tags: php, date

I want to get the total amount of visitors for this week and last week and I got a possible solution for it, but it will not show the correct amount. According to HeidiSQL, this week had 91 visitors and last week 383 visitors. The code below shows that this week had 88 visitors and last week had 56 visitors.

`SELECT COUNT(date_lastactive) FROM visitors WHERE DATE(date_lastactive) = '".date('Y-m-d', strtotime('this week'))."'`

`SELECT COUNT(date_lastactive) FROM visitors WHERE DATE(date_lastactive) = '".date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last week'))."'`

What shall I do to make this SQL request to get the correct amount of visitors or is HeidiSQL the liar here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That looks ok, I’d suspect HeidiSQL first. Try to find out what method it uses to calculate that.

Comment: When I have selected 2 fields in HeidiSQL, it shows the correct amount of selected fields - 2. I'm quite suspicious about if the SQL is correct or not and because of that I asked your guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You select only one day.

```
SELECT COUNT(date_lastactive) FROM visitors WHERE DATE(date_lastactive) > '".date('Y-m-d', strtotime('monday'))."' && DATE(date_lastactive) < '".date('Y-m-d', strtotime('sunday'))."'
```

My code is not correct, but you can see the point.